# DXL convert hex string to char

Tags: hex, ibm-doors

I am parsing an OLE object in doors. 
The representation mixes ascii characters and objdata (hex value of ASCII chars) numbers:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.17134}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\f0\fs20{\object\objemb{\*\objclass Package}\objw4620\objh810{\*\objdata 
01050000
02000000
08000000
5061636b61676500
00000000
00000000
d5c40000
02005f30306132636633392d323936612d346263612d396539342d383039343437336133343035
```

I am able to detect where my file starts using regex and objdata field.

Since my file extension is *.ole, I am going to search for the ".ole" string at the beginning of the objdata field (the long line starting with 0200) and backwards search for the 0200 hex string that.

My question is:

How can I convert from hex representation back to ascii a string in DXL?

Are there functions to perform this task? a simple cast would be enough? Or shall I write my own function to perform this task?

I wasn't able to find any hint on the ref manual, also some keyword or "RTFM page" would be gladly appreciated.

K.R.

Answer (score 0):

The only support that I know of that might help you are `char charOf(int asciiCode)` and `int(char ch)`.

I have not been able to spot ".OLE" (2E 4F 4C 45) or ".ole" (2E 6F 6C 65) in the line you posted, but assuming that these characters (or a combination of upper and lower characters) exist, one approach would be to walk through the objdata character for character (using a Buffer and an integer variable which loops over every character, something like `int i = 0; int high; int low; Char c; while (...) { high = int(buf[i]); low = int(buf[i+1]); c = calculate_character_from_integers(high, low);  i+=2; if c = ... then ...}` and with this approach, whenever you have a new line, have another integer variable that points to the beginning of the line, and when you have something like "current character is 45 or 65 and the character before is 4C or 6C and the one before is 4F or 6F and the one before is 2E, then concatenate the file name from the start of the line." Not sure whether there are any scripts or snippets out in the wild that help here, perhaps you find something in the IBM DeveloperWorks DXL forums (hurry, they will cease to exist in two weeks)

Comment: Hi Mike, 
Thanks to your comments and some extensive googling I was able to create a function (bare minimum) to convert an hex string into ascii string. Of course, I don't know if it is the best I could write, but it works. 
I m going to share if needed.

Comment: Thumbs up!
Of course this would be great - it is always good to get DXL code examples

Answer (score 0):

I had to write a function from scratch based on Mike's reply and [an old thread on IBM forums](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014578479) by user Mathias Mamsch.

I have many doubts on the buffer handling, buts it works fine for my purposes:

This functions performs the Hex2ascii translations of the string.

```
string Hex2Ascii(string &stringIn){
    Buffer buf = create
    string hexval
    while(length(stringIn)>0){
        hexval = iterateOnString(stringIn)
        //print(charOf(intOfHex))
        //print hexval
        //print charOf(intOfHex(hexval))
        buf += charOf(intOfHex(hexval))
        }
    return stringOf buf
}
```

It invokes other two functions; iterateOnString returns two chars to form a byte to be converted and removes it from the original string:

```
string iterateOnString(string &stringIn){
    string StringOut
    int x = length(stringIn)
    if(x<2){
        return ""
        }
    StringOut = stringIn[0:1]
    stringIn = stringIn[2:]
    return StringOut
}
```

then intOfHex converts the hex to int value, then the result is passed to charOf()

```
int intOfHex( string s ) {
        if( "0x" == s[0:1] ) {
                return intOf( realOf( eval_ "return_ (" s ") \"\"" ) )
        } else {
                return intOf( realOf( eval_ "return_ (0x" s ") \"\"" ) )
        }
}
```

Any hint, optimization proposal or critic is welcome.

K.R.